# pdoc doesn't highlight parameter in docstring

Tags: python-3.x, docstring, pdoc

If I generate a html page with `python -m pdoc --html module.py` the output will look like https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzDjk.png

Is there a parameter to get the :param entries in the docstring somehow highlighted?

Comment: Highlighted in what sense?

Comment: at least use a line break like in the docstring, so it gets easier to read

Comment: Seems like pdoc currently only supports [Numpydoc](https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format.html) and [Google-style](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#doc-function-args) docstrings, but not reStructuredText, which is the one you are using (imho verbose and ugly anyway).